# ValueError: Cannot assign error in Django foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three different Django apps in my project: questions, answers, and students. I created demo data for both Question and Student, and I want their objects to be foreign keys of Answer.

Below is the migration file of Answer.

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.apps import apps

questions = apps.get_model('questions', 'Question')
students = apps.get_model('students', 'Student')


def create_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Answer = apps.get_model('answers', 'Answer')
    Answer(question=questions.objects.get(pk="1"),
           student=students.objects.get(pk="2"), answer="Main function").save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('answers', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_data)
    ]
```

When I run `python manage.py migrate`, I get the error below.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<Question: What is this?>": "Answer.question" must be a "Question" instance.
```

Can please someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are questions and student rows with the ids that you need and then set the foreign keys using ids. Example:

```
answer = Answer(answer="Main function")
answer.question_id = 1
answer.student_id = 2
answer.save()
```

P.S. no need to import `apps` from `django.apps`, it's the first argument of `create_data` function. I suggest to use that instead.

Comment: I tried your solution, and another error occured. `django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.`

Comment: as a result, the object cannot be deleted because the id is set to None